# C# nesting multiple try(s) in multiple if(s) then do the catch(s) After that?

Tags: c#, .net

Here What I want to do, but do not know if it will work or if there is a better way:

```
if (condition1){
    try {
            Block1;
    }
} else if (condition2){
    try {
        Block2;
    }
}
catch(ExceptionType1 ex) { process;}
catch(ExceptionType2 ex) { process;}
catch(Exception) {throw;}
```

So is that the best way this could be done?

Comment: You have 2 try(s) but 3 catch(s).

Comment: Put the ifs inside a single try?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef multiple catches for one try are valid - different exception types might need different handling, after all.

Comment: What are you trying to do? try{}else if(){} you will get an error. When you use try, it expects an catch, not an else if.

Comment: @Delsx no like I wrote above it is about if(){try{}}else if(){try{}} else{try{}} catch(){}

Comment: You can get rid of this: `catch(Exception) {throw;}`. If you catch and throw without doing anything else it's the same as not catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can do what you want.

```
try {
    if (condition1) {      
        Block1;
    } else if (condition2) {
        Block2;
    }
}
catch(ExceptionType1 ex) { process;}
catch(ExceptionType2 ex) { process;}
catch(Exception) {throw;}
```

If not, try to put a clear detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax to support exactly, but you might be able to get a similar effect by defining exception classes, and purposely throwing those exceptions in block1 and block2, either through separate try/catches or if/conditonal statements (checking for null, "", etc.)

Here's an example of an exception class behind defined, taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions)

```csharp
[Serializable()]
public class InvalidDepartmentException : System.Exception
{
    public InvalidDepartmentException() : base() { }
    public InvalidDepartmentException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public InvalidDepartmentException(string message, System.Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }

    // A constructor is needed for serialization when an
    // exception propagates from a remoting server to the client.
    protected InvalidDepartmentException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
        System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

In the logic that you want to throw the exceptions in, you just need to define and throw the Exception class you defined. This can be done in a separate catch block, as well

```html
System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("Index is out of range", "index", ex);
        throw argEx;
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Even it is not directly related to what I was asking for it is a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve with your structure in detail. But I see currently no issue in wrapping the whole statement block into a single try-block @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef mentioned and catch different exception types.

Maybe you can think about, to move your both code blocks (Block1 & Block2) into own functions/methods and perform a specific exception handling there and maybe returning some status code from each new block function. This would be a more clean code approach.